# Insert Link dialog hangs using wygwam in Internet Explorer - not other browsers

Tags: wygwam, file-uploads, links, internetexplorer

When editing an entry ... highlight text, click ‘Link’ icon > the wrong dialog appears with ‘Select an Anchor’ and ‘E-mail Address’ ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1kHB.jpg)).

There are similar problems in inserting an image

- Under the ‘Upload’ tab it displays a progress bar in place of the ‘Browse’ button.
- The OK and Cancel buttons do nothing and the only way to remove it is to crash the browser using Task Manager

The problem has appeared within the past month (November 2013) and has affected all three people using IE. It does not occur with FF, Chrome or Safari.

- Windows 7
- IE 11
- EE 2.7.2 (but also occurred with 2.5.2)
- Wygwam 3.2.2 (but also occurred with 2.6.3)

This seems to be an IE issue but is there anything I can do to prevent it?

Kip!

Comment: I just ran into this bug and can confirm it happens in EE 2.4.2 on IE 11 windows 7 with the latest version of wygwam. No issue on a win8 computer.

Comment: I'd say this is very much a bug and needs to be reported directly to the developers.

Comment: good call Anna, have reported it via email to Pixel & Tonic

Comment: I am having the same problem. With Internet Explorer I cannot do links and editing and adding photos is a problem. They need to fix this bug ASAP.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Can confirm this as well - witnessed as I was teaching clients how to use the control panel.

Comment: @CreateSean, any updates from P&T about this one?

Answer (score 3):

This is bug with ckeditor upon which WYGWAM is built. Pixel and Tonic have said fix is coming soon in new release of WYGWAM.

[image: twitter]

Answer (score 1):

We [just released](http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/wygwam-3.3) Wygwam 3.3 which fixes compatibility issues with Internet Explorer 11.