# WYGWAM copy paste is not working

Tags: wygwam

I'm using WYGWAM version 2.5 and I was able to copy paste into the field. Now nothing gets pasted except an empty paragraph.

I had set forcePasteAsPlainTExt set to yes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you working with IE11? I think thereis some problem with this version of IE.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: YES! that was it!

Comment: But then what is the workaround? How do I make it work in IE11?

Answer (score 2):

This is bug with ckeditor upon which WYGWAM is built. You have to update to at least WYGWAM 3.3 which fixes all IE11 issues per this comment: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/20227/69